# Can I transfer my terraria worlds through a flashdrive?

Tags: terraria

I have looked all over the internet trying to find out if you can use a flashdrive to transfer all of my Terraria worlds and characters to another computer. Is it possible to do it this way or do I have to transfer them another way?!

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you should be able to transfer world and character data to another computer.

The files should be located under:

> Documents\My Games\Terraria\Worlds
>
> Documents\My Games\Terraria\Players

Comment: Just grab the whole Terraria folder and move it over!

Comment: I can confirm this does work, I just did it recently with my new computer :)